# CSS Fix container and overflow elements

Tags: css, overflow, containers, fixed

Iam wondering if it is a way to force overflow elements of an fixed container to be on the same line instead of going on a new line.

http://jsfiddle.net/vrSRE/3/

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there's a way.

You have to replace, `float: left` with `display: inline-block`, and add `white-space: nowrap` to the parent element:

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/vrSRE/4/

```
ul {
    width: 300px;
    height: 30px;
    background: red;
    white-space: nowrap
}
li {
    display: inline-block
}
```

If you don't want any space between the elements, the easiest way to fix this new problem is to remove the whitespace in the HTML, like this:

- http://jsfiddle.net/vrSRE/6/

For other options that you probably don't care about to remove the space, see:

- [How to remove the space between inline-block elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5078239/405015)

And lastly, if you care about IE7 support, use this:

- http://jsfiddle.net/vrSRE/7/

Answer (score 1):

See: http://jsfiddle.net/keBFd/

You can use `white-space: nowrap` and `display: inline` - you might not want `display: inline`, though.